# When saving dates to Room database, TypeConverter scrambles the data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I've been working on this for hours, and I can't seem to figure out how to save dates to my Room Sqllite database. I'm basically copying the code to do this wholesale from the Android documentation.

Here's what I have.

Database:

```
@Database(entities = {Review.class},
        version = 3,
        exportSchema=false)
@TypeConverters(DateTypeConverter.class)
public abstract class NotecardDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
...etc...
}
```

Entity:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "review",
        indices = {
                @Index(value = "next_review"),
        }
public class Review {
...Other columns...
    @TypeConverters(DateTypeConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name ="next_review")
    @NonNull
    private Date nextReview;
}
```

Next, my converter:

```
public class DateTypeConverter {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("DateTypeConverter");
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(Long value) {
        if(value != null) {
            log.info("Incoming long: " + value + "\nTo Date: " + new Date(value));
        }
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);

    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
        if(date != null) {
            log.info("Incoming date: " + date + "\n to Long: " + date.getTime());
        }
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the output I get from running that when I try to create some Review objects:

**06-18 18:13:38.522 7081-7098/DateTypeConverter:** 
Incoming date: Mon Jun 18 18:13:38 PDT 2018
  to Long: 1529370818524

**06-18 18:13:38.522 7081-7106/DateTypeConverter:** 
Incoming long: 1529370818
To Date: Sun **Jan** 18 08:49:30 PST **1970**

So it seems that it saves correctly (see first log statement), but when I get the thing out of the database, the last 3 digits of the long are simply chopped off, returning a date in 1970.

Help?

Comment: Your passing value "1529370818" to fromTimestamp().Where from you get this value ?

Comment: That is passed into my function from the Room.

I'm assuming that Room is reading the int value stored in the database and passing it to fromTimestamp.

Comment: It's not int long right ?if value reading  from room then who saves this "1529370818"  value to room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so after much work, I figured out the problem. Thanks for all who were trying to help on this.

I changed from Date to Calendar, though that's not what fixed this problem.

The real issue was that there are two timestamps: the Linux timestamp, which is **milliseconds** since epoch, and the Java/Sqllite timestamp, which is **seconds** since epoch.

In order to have everything play nicely with Sqllite functions and also to save and read properly, here's the my working code:

```
public class DateTypeConverter {
 @TypeConverter
    public static Calendar calendarFromTimestamp(String value) {
        if(value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(NumberUtils.toLong(value)*1000);
        return cal;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String dateToTimestamp(Calendar cal) {
        if(cal == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return "" + cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
    }
}
```

Note the usage of the cal.getTimeInMillis() function, which explicitly calls out that we're doing the **millisecond** timestamp. Then when saving to the database, we divide by 1000 to save the **seconds** timestamp, because the Sqllite date functions deal with the **seconds** timestamp.

Note also that you could probably also use Longs instead of Strings, but the Strings worked for me.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I am having the same problem like you. I implemented yout solution, but I am getting the following error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@TypeConverters(DateTypeConverter.class)`

**Use**

`@TypeConverters({DateTypeConverter.class})`

Comment: My problem is not with the getTime function, but rather with the fact that when I read it out of the database after saving, it's a totally different number. Also, when I tried to store as strings, I had an almost identical problem with the data getting scrambled.